# How can I sort by multiple conditions with different orders?

Tags: ruby, sorting

I'd really like to handle this without monkey-patching but I haven't been able to find another option yet.

I have an array (in Ruby) that I need to sort by multiple conditions.  I know how to use the sort method and I've used the trick on sorting using an array of options to sort by multiple conditions.  However, in this case I need the first condition to sort ascending and the second to sort descending.  For example:

```
ordered_list = [[1, 2], [1, 1], [2, 1]]
```

Any suggestions?

Edit:  Just realized I should mention that I can't easily compare the first and second values (I'm actually working with object attributes here).  So for a simple example it's more like:

```
ordered_list = [[1, "b"], [1, "a"], [2, "a"]]
```

Comment: your modified example can be treated identically to the first one you posted.  The <=> operator will work on any object the same way (in your case, Integer and String objects can both be compared with <=> just fine)

Comment: True, just thought I should mention it rather than risk over simplifying the problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

How about:

```
ordered_list = [[1, "b"], [1, "a"], [2, "a"]]
ordered_list.sort! do |a,b|
  [a[0],b[1]] <=> [b[0], a[1]]
end
```

Comment: Wonderful!  Should have thought of that, knew I was missing something!  Thanks!

Comment: That is RAD! Time to file that away in my ruby tricks book! Kudos!

Comment: @maasha I think `or` doesn't work here because `<=>` returns `0` on equality and `0` doesn't evaluate to `false`. So `1 <=> 1 or 1 <=> 2` returns `0` but `[1,1] <=> [1,2]` returns `-1`.

Comment: how would this work if there are three parameters instead of two?

Eg. I have database enteries with columns date, timestamp, status. I was trying to sort the results by date (descending order), then status (ascending) and then time (ascending order)

Date is not a actual column, i'm retrieving date using timestamp.to_date

Comment: Trying this '@results = @results.sort_by { |x| [-x.timestamp.to_date, x.status, x.timestamp]}' to get desired order is failing.

Answer (score 8):

I was having a nightmare of a time trying to figure out how to reverse sort a specific attribute but normally sort the other two.  Just a note about the sorting for those that come along after this and are confused by the |a,b| block syntax.  You cannot use the `{|a,b| a.blah <=> b.blah}` block style with `sort_by!` or `sort_by`.  It must be used with `sort!` or `sort`.  Also, as indicated previously by the other posters swap `a` and `b` across the comparison operator `<=>` to reverse the sort order.  Like this:

To sort by blah and craw normally, but sort by bleu in reverse order do this:

```
something.sort!{|a,b| [a.blah, b.bleu, a.craw] <=> [b.blah, a.bleu, b.craw]}
```

It is also possible to use the `-` sign with `sort_by` or `sort_by!` to do a reverse sort on numerals (as far as I am aware it only works on numbers so don't try it with strings as it just errors and kills the page).

Assume `a.craw` is an integer.  For example:

```
something.sort_by!{|a| [a.blah, -a.craw, a.bleu]}
```

Answer (score 4):

I had this same basic problem, and solved it by adding this:

```
class Inverter
  attr_reader :o

  def initialize(o)
    @o = o
  end

  def <=>(other)
    if @o.is && other.o.is
      -(@o <=> other.o)
    else
      @o <=> other.o
    end
  end
end
```

This is a wrapper that simply inverts the <=> function, which then allows you to do things like this:

```
your_objects.sort_by {|y| [y.prop1,Inverter.new(y.prop2)]}
```

Answer (score 4):

`Enumerable#multisort` is a generic solution that can be applied to arrays of **any size**, not just those with 2 items. Arguments are booleans that indicate whether a specific field should be sorted ascending or descending (usage below):

```
items = [
  [3, "Britney"],
  [1, "Corin"],
  [2, "Cody"],
  [5, "Adam"],
  [1, "Sally"],
  [2, "Zack"],
  [5, "Betty"]
]

module Enumerable
  def multisort(*args)
    sort do |a, b|
      i, res = -1, 0
      res = a[i] <=> b[i] until !res.zero? or (i+=1) == a.size
      args[i] == false ? -res : res
    end
  end
end

items.multisort(true, false)
# => [[1, "Sally"], [1, "Corin"], [2, "Zack"], [2, "Cody"], [3, "Britney"], [5, "Betty"], [5, "Adam"]]
items.multisort(false, true)
# => [[5, "Adam"], [5, "Betty"], [3, "Britney"], [2, "Cody"], [2, "Zack"], [1, "Corin"], [1, "Sally"]]
```

Comment: Neat!  Thanks, that'll certainly come in handy later.

Comment: Wow - the single line loop would test 99% of the rubyists out there. Very compact.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Glenn's recipe for quite a while now. Tired of copying code from project to project over and over again, I've decided to make it a gem:

http://github.com/dadooda/invert