# Ruby Natural Sort/Order

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm working with the [Challonge](http://www.challonge.com) API and when querying a tournament each match is returned with a `indentifier=` which is A-Z. After the first 26 matches the identifier becomes `AA-AZ` then `BA-BZ`, etc.

When pulling the entire list of matches for a single tournament and trying to use `.sort_by` on the identifier, the results are ordered as:

`A AA AB AC ... B BA BB BC ... C ...`

In order to display the matches correctly they need to be in this order:

`A B C ... AA AB AC ... BA BB BC ...`

I've spent some time searching and couldn't find any really easy way to make this happen. Most posts that I've found dealt with filenames or numbering and I wasn't really sure how to apply it to this situation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

This is a sample response:

`[{"match":{"created_at":"2013-01-09T23:25:22-05:00","has_attachment":false,"id":8148294,"identifier":"CK","loser_id":null,"player1_id":null,"player1_is_prereq_match_loser":true,"player1_prereq_match_id":8148251,"player1_votes":null,"player2_id":null,"player2_is_prereq_match_loser":false,"player2_prereq_match_id":8148293,"player2_votes":null,"round":-9,"started_at":null,"state":"pending","tournament_id":320424,"updated_at":"2013-01-09T23:25:25-05:00","winner_id":null,"prerequisite_match_ids_csv":"8148251,8148293","scores_csv":""}}`

You can see the `"indentifier":"CK"` in there. When using `.length` I keep getting a `undefined method 'length'`. In the controller I'm using `@tournamentlist = tournamentlist.matches.sort...`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or just:

```
ids = ["AA", "A", "C", "CA", "CCC"]
ids.sort { |a,b| [a.length, a] <=> [b.length, b] }
#=> ["A", "C", "AA", "CA", "CCC"]
```

Or, using [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by), even shorter:

```
ids.sort_by { |a| [a.length, a] }
```

Ref: [How can I sort by multiple conditions with different orders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73032/how-can-i-sort-by-multiple-conditions-with-different-orders)

Comment: Yeah, it's much simpler than my version :)

Comment: I added a bit more information in the original question. Having trouble getting it to work correctly.

Comment: Ah just got it. Made the mistake of not including `a.identifier`. Thanks!!

Comment: Great! I added an even shorter version using `sort_by`. Also I removed the `to_s` which wasn't needed.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple, just break that array in groups, where each group contains ids of the same length (one-letter ids, two-letter ids and so on), sort them separately and then merge.

```
ids = %w[A B C AA AB AC BA BB BC AAB BBC CBA].shuffle
ids # => ["CBA", "BA", "C", "BC", "BB", "AC", "BBC", "AAB", "AA", "B", "AB", "A"]

sorted_ids = ids.group_by(&:length).sort{|(len1, _), (len2, _)| len1 <=> len2 }.map do |_, id_group|
  id_group.sort
end.flatten

sorted_ids # => ["A", "B", "C", "AA", "AB", "AC", "BA", "BB", "BC", "AAB", "BBC", "CBA"]
```

#### Let's break this code down:

```
.group_by(&:length)
```

This will process original array and group strings by its length, producing an array where each element is also an array of two elements: first element is length and second element is an array of strings of this length.

```
.sort{|(len1, _), (len2, _)| len1 <=> len2 }
```

This part sorts id groups so that they are appear in order of ascending length (all one-letter strings come first).

```
.map {|_, id_group| id_group.sort }
```

It will take all `(length, strings)` pairs, sort the strings and return. This call produces array of arrays.

```
.flatten
```

`flatten` does what it says: take nested array and "flatten" it, so that there's only no nesting.

Comment: @Sergio what does the underscore in `.sort{(len1,_)...` mean?

Comment: It's a placeholder for ignored variables.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : can you please point me to some documentation about the placeholder for ignored vriables? Also I tried your code on my dev machine and only got {["AA"]} returned. I am using Ruby 1.8.7 does the code work with only Ruby 1.9?

Comment: @Anand: this link, for example: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide. Look for "unused block parameters".

Comment: @Anand: also, I'm not sure about ruby 1.8.7. Try it in ruby 1.9.3.