# Ruby tell sort_by to use different order for different attributes

Tags: ruby, sorting

This question is a lot similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73032/how-can-i-sort-by-multiple-conditions-with-different-orders). The problem is that I cannot use `sort` method because of some reason. I can only use `sort_by`. So, I need to find a way to sort by multiple attributes but with different order for each.

The best answer I can find is by *Gleen* (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73032/how-can-i-sort-by-multiple-conditions-with-different-orders)) but I am concerned about its performance because the object gets copied in `@o = o` (Please correct me if I am wrong in assuming it).

I am thinking whether there a way to stub the `<=>` temporarily while passing it to `sort_by` for the attribute for which I want descending order. Is this possible? I don't want to make any permanent changes in the object also. Also if I have to create a new object without incurring unnecessary overhead (like `@o = o`) to stub `<=>` then that would also be great.

To summarize the behavior what I am hoping to have is the following:

```
> a = [['a', 1], ['b', 2], ['b', 1]]
> a.sort_by { |a| [decending(a[0]), a[1])] } 
=> [['b', 1], ['b', 2], ['a', 1]]
# This should sort the first value in descending 
# and the second in ascending order

def decending(a)
  anything that would change stub <=> method for a
end
```

This is one approach I can think of. Please feel free to suggest any solution which works with `sort_by` and sort by different attributes in different order.

Also I cannot do things like `sort_by { |a| -a }` because the thing I want to sort isn't necessarily numeric. And I want something that would work not only for string but for any object having `<=>` defined.

**EDIT**
It turns out I was vaguely wrong in assuming that `@o = o` copies the object and it isn't much expensive. But I hope there's a better solution out there. One concern is that creating so many objects might create GC bottleneck.

Comment: Correcting you as requested: `@o = o` does not copy an object, it just assigns a variable, so it is not usually expensive or slow. When you are concerned about performance, best thing to do is test and decide whether it is worth trying optimise after you've benchmarked something at the largest scale you need the code to work with.

Comment: @NeilSlater I ran some benchmarks and I found like you said `@o = o` isn't expensive. The reason why I thought `@o = o` copies the object was because, say I do `a = 3`, `b = a` and then I change the value of `b`, the value of `a` remains 3. Why is that? What's the general rule to figure out when the object will be copied and when not?

Comment: That happens with all variables and how they point to objects. If you *assign* the variable in.e.g. `b = 5`, that doesn't change the value of a "number" object, it assigns the `5` object to `b`. The trick is to notice when you are *assigning* an object to a variable and when you are modifying the object. It is actually not possible to modify a numeric object in Ruby . . . each number is its own object.

Comment: I understand it now. Thank You!